# Angular 5 http requests are always cached even if server response changes

Tags: php, caching, angular5

I have a folder  'uploads' inside my assets folder. I want to simply upload an image there and my app recognize that image (.jpg) and add to a carousel.

My PHP file reads the directory, then returns a Json with the files name. Whenever I upload a file there, the PHP recognizes and put it in the json, as below:

```
{
  imgs: [
  {
        filename: "01_Comment-T.jpg",
        comment: "Comment T"
   },
   {
        filename: "02.jpg",
        comment: ""
    }
]}
```

But I'm facing a cache problem in the Angular 5 app. Even when the PHP changes the JSON response, my APP still using the old form of the Json. Even when I press F5, reload or clean the browser cache.

I exhausted all options, including putting headers both on servers and the requests, with interceptors, .htaccess, html and wherever. All the easy options I tried. There is no clear documentation on that outthere.

My Angular request:

```
getPage(page){
     let timeStamp = +new Date();
     let str = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 3);
    return this.http.get('http://jetcon.local/server/'+page+ '?'+str+'=' + 
   timeStamp);}
```

In the Component

```
this.pageData.getPage('construcao').subscribe(
   data => { this.page = data; },
   err => console.error(err)
 );
```

I tried to force a cache removal adding dinamically a get variable.

I appreciate your help! Thank you.

Comment: What did you set your headers to when you attempted?  Does visiting the endpoint with something like postman produce the same results?

Comment: Hi Guys. Just found the error. It was something really dumb, but I will state here since someone may stuck in the same stupidity:
`this.http.get('http://jetcon.local/server/')`

I was using the local URL in my call, and, my browser was routing to my local filesystem.

Even opening the prod URL, it was still being routed on my browser due to the hosts file. **LOL**. I think I need a beer.